# What is vertex connectivity of triangle graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

On Wikipedia, it says that the vertex connectivity of a [triangle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_graph) is 2.

In my opinion, if we removed any 2 vertices in a triangle graph, then the remaining vertex would be a trivially connected graph. And even if we remove all 3 vertices, then the empty graph is also trivially connected. Perhaps a triangle graph doesn't have a vertex connectivity?

So what is the vertex connectivity of a triangle graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual definition of vertex connectivity (a graph is $k$-vertex-connected if we cannot disconnect it by removing fewer than $k$ vertices) doesn't really work for the triangle graph or for any other complete graph.

(You could argue that the empty graph is not connected, in which case the triangle graph *could* have vertex connectivity $3$.)

However, for all other graphs, an alternate characterization of vertex connectivity exists: a graph is $k$-vertex-connected if, for any two vertices $v$ and $w$, there exist $k$ paths from $v$ to $w$ which disjoint except at their endpoints. (The equivalence between these is [Menger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem).) So we can take this definition instead, and get the same notion for non-complete graphs.

Under this definition, the triangle graph is $2$-vertex-connected, because there are two disjoint paths between any two of its vertices, and in general the complete graph $K_n$ is $(n-1)$-vertex-connected.

---

In fact, to match this result, we often add a clause into the usual definition to make it work for complete graphs in the same way. For example, [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph) of a $k$-vertex-connected graph is

> a connected graph $G$ is said to be $k$-vertex-connected (or $k$-connected) if *it has more than $k$ vertices* and remains connected whenever fewer than $k$ vertices are removed.

The condition "it has more than $k$ vertices" only comes into play for a complete graph $K_n$, and ensures that its vertex connectivity is $n-1$.

Comment: Some books define the vertex connectivity as the least number of vertices whose removal results in a graph which is either disconnected or has just one vertex.

Comment: @bof And it's worth mentioning that the "or just has one vertex" clause only comes into play for complete graphs.